# Fibonacci sequence datastructure

Tags: data-structures, queue, stack

It is known that Fibonacci sequence is {0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21... ...}, try to write recursive functions and non-recursive functions, calculate the values of 10th numbers, 29th numbers, 50th numbers and 64th numbers of Fibonacci sequence on the computer, and compare the time consumed by the two, the performance of the two design methods is analyzed.

Comment: How far did you get already? Where do you need help?

Comment: I don't understand how to start.

Comment: I would first write down the recursive definition of the sequence in a mathematical way, and then try to write it in your favorite programming language. Once we get that working (we can probably help when you get stuck – provided that you share your code), you can play with it and think of a non-recursive approach. But I'd say first step first.